# Reading a response in Ajax php and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I can't get the code to work and redirect to 2 different pages depending if the information is correct or not...

So far I have this on my login page:

```
$(function () {
$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'newfile.php',
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        success: function (response){
        alert(response); 
                    if (success.text="Username or Password incorrect")
                        window.location.href = "index.php"; 
                    else if (success.text="login successful") {
                        window.location.href = "login_success.html";
                    } else {  
                    }
            }
        })
})
```

and the information Im reading from is (from another page):

```
<?php    
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die(" Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
echo "Connected successfully";
}
$sql="SELECT myusername, mypassword FROM user WHERE myusername = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $myusername) . "' and mypassword = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $mypassword) . "';";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows >0) {
    echo "login successful";
} else {
    echo "Username or Password incorrect";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: What happens currently? Any errors thrown?

Comment: No but it does echo correctly, it doesnt redirect though

Comment: It does say success is not defined

Comment: Oh, that's a JS error. Shouldn't it be `if (response="Username or Password incorrect")`?

Comment: I tried both response and response.text but when I did it would only redirect to the first page in the if statement and not the second even if the details were wrong

Comment: That sounds like the PHP/SQL might not be working as expected then. Can you add to the PHP?

Comment: Yes there are no errors with the php and database either

Comment: An incorrectly structured query could return no results but also not have an error. Do you know that the query works when you execute it? Did you error log or output the return somewhere?

Comment: The query works as I havent changed it at all since making it

Comment: Yes it says database connected successfully

Comment: I dont understand what you mean

Comment: yes but I had it commented out until now

Comment: Yes it is a text box

Comment: Yes they are using post and are unhashed

Comment: I have updated my answer u r usung = sign for comparing I should be == in ajax if else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will work for you try this:

```
if (response=="usernames or Password incorrect") {
    window.location.href = "index.php";
} 
else if (response=="login successful") 
{
    window.location.href = "login_success.html";
 } 
else { }
```

Use this code in ajax success. Actually you are using simple **ECHO** in PHP and using response.text in ajax success.

UPDATE:

**you are using = sign for comparing it should be == operator for compare.**

UPDATE 2:

i suggest to use status as true false not long string in php like:

```
if ($result->num_rows >0) {
    echo true;
} else {
    echo false;
}
```

**Than in ajax response:**

```
if(response == true){
// Success url
}
else {
// failure url
}
```

Comment: Its still only going to the same page for both of the results

Comment: On which pagw succes.html or login.php @sgiga

Comment: @chris85 answer updated is comparing symbol issue it should be == not =

Comment: In the future please read question and comments prior to answering. Might want to give OP link as well for additional reading, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: Its actually stopped redirecting altogether now

Comment: @chris85 my friend I accepted its my mistake I will read all comments in future chk my answer. And suggest

Comment: If redirection is stop than it means u r not getting the response . Now check console.log(response); @sgiga

Comment: I have an alert(response) in my code and it does say login successful

Comment: That might have a newline in it still, check the console; or use `trim`. It is recommend you not close your PHP file because sometimes there is whitespace after the close `?>`. From the manual..`omitting it is helpful when using include or require, so unwanted whitespace will not occur at the end of files` http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Comment: How would I use trim?

Comment: trim("text"); in php

Comment: `response.trim()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: Good suggestion @chris85

Comment: @devpro it is a javascript issue (possibly, if trim resolves it) because the closing PHP block sends a newline.

Comment: No difference made, I did try trim earlier

Comment: Than why not use this..... just echo true in success and echo false in failer in php file than just use if(response == true) no need to trim @chris85

Comment: Sgiga use true false instead of long string

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: @chris85 need yur input becuase u r senior than to me.. plz guide if I wrong

Comment: Thankyou very much for that!! both of you :)

Comment: U r always welcome If u think this answer solve yur issue than mark as accepted it will help for others. @sgiga

Answer (score 1):

The variable success will be undefined inside the success callback function. So the next line will not be executed. So the page will not be redirected. According to your php code , you need to check if  response is equal to the corresponding result of not.